# Pagination best practices and "pagination indexes"

Tags: sql, postgresql, api, pagination

Yesterday I went to add pagination to a chat service. I've implemented pagination a hundred times before using either page/per_page or start/end arguments, and I've always been aware that there is the potential for the order or offsets to change between page loads, but in the case of this chat service, that is much more likely to happen. My first approach was to use the updated_at column and have subsequent requests just pass something like "updated_after" but in this case, we often import multiple rooms at once that could easily have the same updated_at (down to the millisecond) for the same user.

One solution I found was to use an update count, or index that gets incremented (table wide) each time a row is updated. I've implemented it using a [postgres SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html) column that I set it to `nextval('room_update_count')` each time the room is updated (this could be a trigger but I wanted more control). Then I can just sort on that column and use a simple `update_index < $next` to get the following page.

However, I haven't been able to find any references to any technique like this. It seems to work perfectly but I'm skeptical that I'm not seeing some issue with it. I feel like I can't be the first person to come up with this idea, and that if I could just think of the correct name for it I would find other examples of it.

Is this a known technique? What are other ways to solve the pagination offset issue?

Comment: it is all [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: I second the advice not to use `OFFSET`, but that's off topic. I think your technique to exclude recent modifications works fine for updates and inserts, but it won't keep deleted rows from disappearing.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments! That's exactly what I needed. I ended up dropping the sequence column and just using updated_at and id like that linked article suggests and it works great.